# Asp core published API routing issue

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a MVC app and an API, both in ASP Core (respectively 2.2 and 3.0), which are published on 2 different servers under IIS 10. The web app runs well but I have an unexcpected issue with the API : routing is broken.

Here is an example method I'm using to get a city from its zipcode (codePostal) :

```
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class CommunesController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ICommuneService _communeService;

    public CommunesController(ICommuneService communeService)
    {
        _communeService = communeService;
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet("{codePostal}")]
    public IActionResult GetCommunesFromCP(string codePostal)
    {
        IList<CommuneDto> resCommunes = _communeService.GetCommunesFromCP(codePostal);

        if (resCommunes == null || resCommunes.Count == 0)
            return NotFound();
        else
            return Ok(resCommunes);
    }
}
```

If I call this method with the url https://mydomain.fr/communes/38000, I get a 404 error. If I use the classic query string syntax https://mydomain.fr/communes?codePostal=38000, it works ! I don't understand why this happens. Also when I have several GET methods with RESTful naming in a controller, the wrong one is called because routing is lost !  Everything worked well in debug, but I've been struggling with this for hours since I deployed my API.

Here is my API Configure method from Startup.cs, if it can help :

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseAuthentication();

    // global cors policy
    app.UseCors(x => x
        .AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader());

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

Comment: Willing to bet that the controller is intercepting you get request and translating your param 3800 as an integer and not as a string and not finding the correct route when its doing its routing.. Do you still get a 404 when passign an obvious string to the endpoint?

Comment: @TravisActon Yes I do, I did the test. The problem is bigger than that : in a controller, if I have two GET methods on the same endpoint, one with a parameter, one without, I'm always routed to the one without params because routing of parameters is not done properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `[Route("GetCommunesFromCP/{codePostal}")]` before your method, below you method after changes:

```
   [AllowAnonymous]
   [Route("GetCommunesFromCP/{codePostal}")]
    public IActionResult GetCommunesFromCP(string codePostal)
    {
        IList<CommuneDto> resCommunes = _communeService.GetCommunesFromCP(codePostal);

        if (resCommunes == null || resCommunes.Count == 0)
            return NotFound();
        else
            return Ok(resCommunes);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is a restful API, I intentionnaly did not expose the method name, it's the HTTP verb and the parameters that will give routing information.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem : the location of app.UseAuthentication() in Startup.cs was wrong. I moved it before app.UseCors(...) and routing worked fine after I re-published the API. I don't see the link between the location of app.UseAuthentication() and the problem, since in both cases it was before app.UseRouting() :

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseAuthentication();

    // global cors policy
    app.UseCors(x => x
        .AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader());

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```